# Can't assign value to datepicker field

Tags: c#, jquery, datepicker

I have a field StartDate with Jquery datepicker.
datepicker is working fine.
But when I assign value from code behind, the field is showing nothing.

If I remove the `hasDatePicker` class from field, it displays date correctly.

I need to assign date value from DB when perform edit option, also need datepicker on that field.

Here my code:

$(document).ready(function () {      //Add this line (and it's closing line)        
        $("#ctl00_cpBusinessMasterPagePlaceHolder_txtStartDate").datepicker();
        $("#ctl00_cpBusinessMasterPagePlaceHolder_txtStartDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
});

**Code Behind:**

txtStartDate.Text = mode == "relist" ? System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() :( job.StartDate!=null? Convert.ToDateTime(job.StartDate.ToString()).ToShortDateString() : "");

Comment: Some code will be useful to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Please show the code that is failing.

Comment: Here my javascript code:
    $(document).ready(function () {      $("#ctl00_cpBusinessMasterPagePlaceHolder_txtStartDate").datepicker();        $("#ctl00_cpBusinessMasterPagePlaceHolder_txtStartDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
});

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="text_field1 datepicker"></asp:TextBox>

**Code Behind:**  
  txtStartDate.Text = mode == "relist" ? System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() :( job.StartDate!=null? Convert.ToDateTime(job.StartDate.ToString()).ToShortDateString() : "");

Answer (score 0):

Since the date format of the datepicker is `dd/mm/yy`, you need to use the same date format in the code behind. Change `ToShortDateString()` to `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`. Assuming that `job.StartDate` is a datetime, `Convert.ToDateTime(job.StartDate.ToString()).ToShortDateString()` is not necessary, you can just do `job.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` instead.

```
txtStartDate.Text = mode == "relist" ? System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") 
    : (job.StartDate != null ? job.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below code. now it is working fine.
i can retrieve the value in own format also set value in my own format

$("#ctl00_cpBusinessMasterPagePlaceHolder_txtStartDate").datepicker();
 $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });

Thanks friends, who are all trying to help me.